# Evaluate $\int_1^4 \frac{1}{x^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{x} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus

The correct answer is (4*2^.5/3)-(5*5^.5/12)

I set $u = x^{-2}$

therefore, $du = -2x^{-3} dx$

$dx = x^3 / 2$

The next step I took was: $u(1/2)(1+x^{-1})^{.5}(-x^{-2})+C$

When I plug $4$ and $1$ into these equations, I arrive at $5^{.5} / 80$ for $F(4)$ and $2^{.5} / 4$ for $F(1)$

I am going seriously wrong somewhere, and I can't figure out what I am doing here.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find
$$
\int_1^4 \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/2}\;dx
$$
It looks like you are using integration by substitution. Maybe try with $u = 1 + \frac{1}{x}$. Then
$$
-du = x^{-2}dx
$$
and you you get
$$
\int_?^? -\sqrt{u}\; du = \dots
$$

Comment: Thanks, it's starting to make sense now. I need to learn how to think in a different manner when dong these problems.